# Checkbox alert, select max 4 items

Tags: javascript, forms, count

I have a form with checkboxes. Max 4 items needs to be selected. If selecting more then an Alert pops up. I have it working when I use the same name="" but that really needs to be different. Anyone knows how to do this?

The script I have: (ckb needs to be ckb1 + ckb2 + ckb3...)

```
function chkcontrol(j) {
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++){
        if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
            total =total +1;}
        if(total > 4){
            alert("Selecteer a.u.b. maximaal 4 workshops") 
            document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false ;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My form html code:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" name="form1">
<span>Workshops selection: (max 4)</span><br><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="ckb1" value="blabla first" onclick='chkcontrol(0)'; /> blabla first<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb2" value="blabla 2" onclick='chkcontrol(1)'; /> blabla 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb3" value="blabla 3" onclick='chkcontrol(2)'; /> blabla 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb4" value="blabla 4" onclick='chkcontrol(3)'; /> blabla 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb5" value="blabla 5" onclick='chkcontrol(4)'; /> blabla 5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb6" value="blabla 6" onclick='chkcontrol(5)'; /> blabla 6<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb7" value="blabla 7" onclick='chkcontrol(6)'; /> blabla 7<br>

<input class="btn" class="cursor" name="Sent" type="submit" value="Sent" />
</form>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usq2aeLL/1/

Working one but needs different name="xxx": https://jsfiddle.net/usq2aeLL/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a common class to select the elements instead

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb1" class="myBox" value="blabla first" />
```

and then

```
function chkcontrol() {
    var total = 0;
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.myBox');

    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].checked) {
            total = total + 1;
        }
        if (total > 4) {
            alert("Selecteer a.u.b. maximaal 4 workshops")
            elems.checked = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/usq2aeLL/3/)

Preferably you'd swap out the inline event handlers with `addEventListener` as well.